# Solidworks File Headers/Signatures

Tags: file, hex, recovery, solidworks, file-recovery

I recently posted this question on the Solidworks Forum, and we weren't able to figure it out. So I'm bringing this question here.

Can anybody help me get the file header/signatures for solidworks part files (2017)?

I've actually spent a lot of time trying to figure this out, but I'm completely out of my comfort zone, and have almost no idea what I'm doing.

I need the file header in order to restore some files that got deleted. I'm using Stellar Phoenix Windows Data Recovery Professional software. It allows you to add your own headers so that it can find your files if they're not natively supported by the software. I need to add the solidworks part file header so that I can recover those files.

[Picture of the dialogue box for the recovery software](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8eCCF.jpg)

If you look at the picture, you can see that I need the header (in hexadecimal) and the offset, along with some other file specifics. The header can only be a maximum of 8 bytes.

For those of you that may have noticed the "I don't know how to add header", I already tried it. It seemed to be working fine, it restored all the files, but when I tried to click on one of the restored files, solidworks couldn't open it. I believe it's because of a incorrect header, which is why I'm manually trying to get one. When I opened the file with notepad++ with a hex add in, it showed that it was filled with '0's.

Anyway, I tried comparing solidworks files in notepad++ with a hex add in (as previously spoken of) and I noticed a couple repetitions, but I have no idea what to do with them

```
File 1
83 f6 a5 b4 *20 20 20 04* 47 1d bd 27 fb 7a 79 b8 
36 40 03 c5 4c *14 20 06 20 08 20 3b* f8 fe 1b 0a 
09 20 20 42 02 20 20 85 04 20 20 16 20 20 20 37
File 2
53 f8 4d b1 *20 20 20 04* c6 d1 a7 76 89 81 f6 af
a8 fe 2e 3b a9 *14 20 06 20 08 20 3b* f8 d8 1b 0e
0a 20 20 83 02 20 20 07 05 20 20 07 20 20 20 05
```

*Something happened between copying and pasting and it's not the exact same for some reason. I believe this is because of the way the hex is. I can try to write it by hand if anyone wants the exact data.

Here's what one of the 'recovered' files looks like

```
20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20
20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20
20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20
```

*they're actually all zeros but it doesn't copy and paste exactly as said previously.

Anyway, if anybody can help me figure this out it would be great.

Here's a couple solidworks part files if anybody wants to look at them:

```
https://ufile.io/b6tfr
https://ufile.io/nyvsr
https://ufile.io/xbazk
https://ufile.io/qqqc7
https://ufile.io/6608g
```

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm correct but it looks like by header your recovery software means sequence of bytes that every file that you wish to recover will start with. While this may work for some file formats, sldprt files do not have shared sequence of bytes that they start with. So I don't think you'll be able to use that feature of Phoenix recovery here.

Comment: Oh. That's too bad. Thanks for the reply :)

Comment: best to contact solidworks technical support for this issue.